# Want this cut-out part to be seperate object, how?

Tags: scene, knife-tool

I have cut out this selected piece with a knife and i want it to be a part of its own in the right colon (scene section).
Right now its still part of the cube around of it. What is the option for this?

[image]

Comment: If I get it right: select all vertices you wish to separate, then press P > selection

Comment: yes u got it right, thanks. It was so simple but couldnt think of it :)